# Workflow for releasing two versions of application with some differences

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mercurial

I need to release two versions ("**A**" and "**B**") of WPF application at the same time. The differences  between versions are usually constant.

The differences are the following:

- application name (and main exe-file name);
- splashscreen and logo;
- exe file's icon;
- resources file (with text strings);
- strings in AssemblyInfo like manufacturer etc.

Functionality is the same.

How can I use mercurial for this situation?

I use two separete named-branches for each version and I merge them with my development branch every time when I need to release them. For version "**A**" it works fine, but I have to change "**B**" everytime when I merge it: I have to change resources, fix AssemblyInfo, rename app, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wonder if you really need to maintain two version of the source code to achieve the same functionality.

You may find that implementing a feature toggle solution will reduce the need to release and maintain versions. The following article by Martin Fowler provides a good overview of feature toggles.

http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FeatureToggle.html

Comment: @HighCore Yep,a certain amount of fanboyism ok.But not more.:)

Comment: Hm, I even found special library for feature toggles in .Net: https://github.com/jason-roberts/FeatureToggle Thank you, I'll try this pattern now.

Comment: But can I change the app name (and exe file name), icon, etc?

Comment: (Can I use FT for static resources?)

Comment: Depending on the type of executable, you may have different options (e.g. service installer), but regardless you should be able to use a Pre-Build Event.